# With a USB SD card reader, the SD card only shows up if it is inserted before the USB reader is inserted

Tags: usb, sd-card

I'm running Alpine Linux `3.17.0` on kernel `5.15.79-0-rpi`, on a RaspberryPi Zero 2 W.

I have a USB card reader, and an SD card.

When I have the SD card inserted into the card reader, and then insert the card reader into the USB slot, it automatically mounts and I can access the card's contents.

When inserted in this way, `dmesg` shows that it mounts as `sda1`:

```
[ 1425.822741] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00021501
[ 1425.996620] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
[ 1425.996871] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
[ 1426.183766] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=aaaa, idProduct=8816, bcdDevice=13.08
[ 1426.183796] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1426.183817] usb 1-1: Product: MXT USB Device
[ 1426.183835] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: MXTronics
[ 1426.183853] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 150101v01
[ 1426.186055] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1426.187527] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[ 1427.235838] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     MXT-USB  Storage Device   1501 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[ 1427.241320] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 62333952 512-byte logical blocks: (31.9 GB/29.7 GiB)
[ 1427.241930] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[ 1427.241968] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[ 1427.242402] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
[ 1427.242429] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 1427.251302]  sda: sda1
[ 1427.253944] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

However, when the card reader is inserted without the SD card, and I insert it afterwards, it does not mount. `sda1` does not show up at all, and I can not seem to manually mount it.

When inserted in this way, `dmesg` shows:

```
[ 1590.567395] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00021501
[ 1590.741262] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
[ 1590.741495] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
[ 1590.928339] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=aaaa, idProduct=8816, bcdDevice=13.08
[ 1590.928368] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1590.928389] usb 1-1: Product: MXT USB Device
[ 1590.928408] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: MXTronics
[ 1590.928426] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 150101v01
[ 1590.930159] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1590.931758] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[ 1591.972410] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     MXT-USB  Storage Device   1501 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[ 1591.975152] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Media removed, stopped polling
[ 1591.979599] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

When inserting or removing just the SD card, no further messages show up in `dmesg`.

The card reader shows up under `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID aaaa:8816 MXTronics MXT USB Device
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux 5.15.79-0-rpi dwc_otg_hcd DWC OTG Controller
```

Nothing related to the SD card shows up under `lsblk` however:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0         7:0    0 27.1M  1 loop /.modloop
sda           8:0    1    0B  0 disk 
mmcblk0     179:0    0 14.8G  0 disk 
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0  200M  0 part /media/mmcblk0p1
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0 14.6G  0 part /media/mmcblk0p2
```

At this point I'm a bit unsure of where the problem might be. Some forum posts say that changing the card reader worked, but I have tried the three different USB card readers that I have available, and all three have the same issue.

I've also seen some posts talk about installing different modules, but that seems unlikely because the card does mount successfully, just only if I insert the reader and card together at the same time.

The important bit seems to be the `Media removed, stopped polling` line. There is one post that talks about `CONFIG_HOTPLUG_PCI_*`, but I don't believe the USB card reader is a PCI device?

Comment: This is normal behaviour regardless of OS

Comment: @roaima Is it? It seems a bit odd that one would have to remove and reinsert the whole card reader to e.g. insert a new SD card. Is there something I'm misunderstanding? This is not how SD card readers that are integrated into laptops etc. work.

Comment: @Kusalananda I think you're describing the difference between a simple USB adaptor such as described in the question, and some more complex device. Speaking from experience with a Windows platform i have used a number of usb - SD card adaptors and without exception they need the card inserted into the adaptor before the adaptor is plugged into a usb port. On the other hand I recognise your description too. Maybe such devices are different to the one described here. I don't know for sure

Comment: I have never had to insert the card before the reader. However, have you tried running `rescan-scsi-bus.sh` to see if it shows up?

Comment: Additionally, do you get udisks / udisks2 ? And in the second experiment, do you get the udisks daemon running ?

Comment: I was wondering if this was considered normal behaviour, or if the specific readers I have don't support hot swapping, but I connected the reader to my laptop and it supported inserting/removing the SD cards as desired. I tested using a MacBook if that changes anything.

Comment: I installed `rescan-scsi-bus.sh` through the `sg3_utils` package, and when running after inserting/removing the SD card it didn't seem to find any devices:

```
0 new or changed device(s) found.          
0 remapped or resized device(s) found.
0 device(s) removed.
```

Comment: My system doesn't seem to have udisks/udisks2. I'll read up on that and report back if I find anything.

Comment: I also found some further information on my system's setup. It is using `mdev` to auto mount devices. I inspected the mdev log, and it does trigger events when the USB reader is inserted/removed, but does not trigger events when the reader is plugged in and the SD card is inserted/removed. This matches my original findings, so it might be related to mdev, or something further upstream.

Comment: Your penultimate comment will make everybody here happy. This is normal behavior… when no udisks-(like) daemon is running. Point is then : Is it normal behavior that your system does not run the udisks daemon. Configuration ? Using *hal* instead ?